# Batch moving all files to variable folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch process that downloads several files in June, organized by day. After downloading them, I process them, then I'd like to move them into a folder, separated by day. For single-digit days, call them 01, 02, ... etc. So I create the folder, then move them:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "year=2015"

for /l %%x (9, 1, 10) do (
    (download files here to C:\mydir\)
    (process files here in C:\mydir\)
    SET "day=0000%%x"
    mkdir C:\mydir\files\%year%-06-!day:~-2!
    move C:\mydir\*.* C:\mydir\files\%year%-06-!day:~-2!
 )
```

Here's the error I usually get:

```
 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

In that case, the folder is created, but the files aren't moved. Instead, they just disappear.

Another one:

```
 The directory name is invalid.
 Cannot move multiple files to a single file.
```

Here, the files just stick around.

I would say after running it 100 times, I receive one of those message almost always. Once, it moved as expected. Another few times, it moved all but one of the files (and that one just disappeared). Another time, the console said it moved, but they didn't.

I have lots of code surrounding this block, so perhaps it's interfering with this part; however, no variable names are being repeated, and I'm running this with all other processes commented out. So I'm stuck here. I found the date-naming syntax on another SO thread, so perhaps I don't understand that fully enough.

Comment: `move C:\mydir\*.* C:\mydir\files\%year%-06-!day:~-2!\\` End up the target directory with a trailing backslash?

Comment: Yep, tried that. Didn't make a difference, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is raised if there is nothing to move. See next example (copied and pasted from my CLI window):

```
==>move D:\xxxx\*.* D:\xxx
D:\xxxx\abc.txt
D:\xxxx\cba.txt
        2 file(s) moved.

==>move D:\xxxx\*.* D:\xxx
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

==>
```

I misunderstand why do you loop the code twice (for `%x=9` and `%x=10`): [read more about `FOR /L` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html). However, try `if exist C:\mydir\*.ext ...` where `.ext` is an extension of a downloaded file. Note that `exist C:\mydir\*.*` evaluates to `true` for any (even empty) existing folder.

To catch the second error (sounds as `move` target is considered to be a file, so end up it with a trailing backslash), I'd rewrite the script as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "year=2015"
for /l %%x in (9, 1, 10) do (
    rem (download files here to C:\mydir\)
  rem insert here: if exist C:\mydir\*.ext (
    rem (process files here in C:\mydir\)
    SET "day=0000%%x"
    call :myMove
  rem insert here closing parenthesis of 'if' command: )
)
endlocal
goto :eof

:myMove
  echo ON >NUL
  mkdir "C:\mydir\files\%year%-06-%day:~-2%" 2>NUL
  move "C:\mydir\*.*" "C:\mydir\files\%year%-06-%day:~-2%\"
  @ECHO OFF >NUL
goto :eof
```

Comment: Looping code twice was just to illustrate I was running it on multiple days, so I would create folders for day 9, day 10 in this case. Anyway, using % instead of ! surrounding `day` worked - thanks.